# Rate limiting with tc on vlans

Tags: opensuse, tc

I have found this prior answer (https://serverfault.com/questions/461153/vlan-based-rate-limiting-using-tc), however attempting to add the vlan match to my script yields :

> What is "handle"? Usage: ... basic [ match EMATCH_TREE ]
>                    [ action ACTION_SPEC ] [ classid CLASSID ]
>
> Where: SELECTOR := SAMPLE SAMPLE ...
>          FILTERID := X:Y:Z
>          ACTION_SPEC := ... look at individual actions
>
> NOTE: CLASSID is parsed as hexadecimal input.

My script is as below. It works fine with a phyisical interface, but if I replace `em1` wtih `vlanXXX` (where XX is the VLAN number !) it fails.

The OS is openSUSE LEAP15 (4.12.14-lp150.12.16-default #1 SMP Tue Aug 14 17:51:27 UTC 2018 (28574e6) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

```
#!/bin/bash
tc qdisc add dev vlanXX root handle 1:0 htb default 10
tc class add dev vlanXX parent 1:0 classid 1:10 htb rate 1000mbit ceil 1000mbit prio 0
tc class add dev vlanXX parent 1:0 classid 1:20 htb rate  15mbit ceil 16mbit prio 0
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 20
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -p tcp --dport 443 -j MARK --set-mark 20
tc filter add dev vlanXX parent 1:0 prio 0 protocol ip handle 20 fw flowid 1:20
```

This is the filter VLAN match I have been trying based on the other answer:

`tc filter add dev em1 parent 1:0 prio 0 protocol ip basic match "meta(vlan mask 0xfff eq 0x07D1)" handle 20 fw flowid 1:20`

***UPDATE:

I have found this syntax installs ok:

```
 tc filter add dev em1 parent 1:0 prio 0 protocol ip handle 20 basic match "meta(vlan mask 0xfff eq 0xB2)" flowid 1:20
```

> sudo tc filter show dev em1 filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 49152
>
> basic  filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 49152 basic handle 0x14
>
> flowid 1:20    meta(vlan mask 0x00000fff eq 178)

But I can't figure out how to get the `fw` syntax to work (so that I can use iptables to set which ports the rate limit applies to instead of rate limiting the entire interface)

e.g. this does not work:

```
 sudo tc filter add dev em1 parent 1:0 prio 0 protocol ip handle 20 fw basic match "meta(vlan mask 0xfff eq 0xB2)" flowid 1:20
```

> basic match "meta(vlan mask 0xfff eq 0xB2)" flowid 1:20
>
> What is "basic"? Usage: ... fw [ classid CLASSID ] [ indev DEV ] [ action
>   ACTION_SPEC ]
>          CLASSID := Push matching packets to the class identified by CLASSID with format X:Y
>                     CLASSID is parsed as hexadecimal input.
>          DEV := specify device for incoming device classification.
>          ACTION_SPEC := Apply an action on matching packets.
>          NOTE: handle is represented as HANDLE[/FWMASK].
>                FWMASK is 0xffffffff by default.

Answer (score 1):

The order of parameters is important. From the man page:

```
tc [ OPTIONS ] filter [ add | change | replace | delete | get ] dev DEV
   [ parent qdisc-id | root ] [ handle filter-id ] protocol protocol prio priority 
   filtertype [ filtertype specific parameters ] flowid flow-id
```

According to this, the handle specification should be before `protocol`.

Although the tc command itself shows it the other way around:

```
$ tc filter help
Usage: tc filter [ add | del | change | replace | show ] [ dev STRING ]
[...]
   [ pref PRIO ] protocol PROTO [ chain CHAIN_INDEX ]
   [ estimator INTERVAL TIME_CONSTANT ]
   [ root | ingress | egress | parent CLASSID ]
   [ handle FILTERID ] [ [ FILTER_TYPE ] [ help | OPTIONS ] ]
     ^^^
```

But it's still before FILTER_TYPE which is the actual filter criteria.

In your command:

> ```
> tc filter add dev em1 parent 1:0 prio 0 protocol ip
>    basic match "meta(vlan mask 0xfff eq 0x07D1)"
>    handle 20 fw flowid 1:20
> ```

... the handle is after the filter (basic match ...) and thus, it's not recognized anymore. Of course there could be a filter with its own `handle` parameter, but I think it's not the case here.

Please note I haven't checked whether this filter makes any sense otherwise, but the "what is handle?" parse error should be caused by the parameter order alone. I also didn't get this error for the other commands you showed.

Comment: ignore this comment... I'll update the original question, its neater !

Comment: "Error talking to the kernel" usually means `tc` and kernel disagree what should be supported. This can be a bug in `tc`, but usually down to old kernel version or missing drivers/modules.

Comment: I have updated my update. Any ideas most welcome !

Comment: @LittleCode I haven't used `tc` in a long while and it shows... ;) I guess you can't mix tc filters. I guess you have to pick one that does the thing you want, or use more subclasses with a new filter chain for each class. If you could find a way to only mark vlan packets with iptables, you'd just need check the mark alone in tc (assuming the mark isn't lost). Sorry for confusion